# Can you detect homological dimensions from homology?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Suppose you are given a bounded chain complex $M$ over a commutative ring $R$.

Is there a clear relation between homological dimensions of $M$ and homological dimensions of its cohomologies?

For example, suppose I know that $injdim(H^i(M))<\infty$ for all $i$, does this imply
that $injdim(M)<\infty$? what about the converse? what about projective and flat dimension?

Any reference for this?

Comment: What do you mean by the homological/injective dimension of a chain complex?

Comment: If you mean the minimum length of an injective complex that is quasi-isomorphic to the original complex, then I think the answer is yes, by writing the complex up to quasi-isomorphism as an iterated extension of its homology groups and applying the mapping cone to construct an injective resolution of the complex from the injective resolution of the homology groups.

Comment: @WillSawin do you mean complexes of injective modules? By contrast, injective complexes are contractible, I think.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Yes, I mean precisely that.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the ring $R = \mathbb Z/4$.  Then $\mathbb Z/4$    is both injective and projective over itself, whereas $\mathbb Z/2$ has infinite projective and injective dimension.

We could have  the chain complex: $ 0 \to  \mathbb Z/4 \to^{\cdot 2} \mathbb Z/4 \to 0$  with the homologies having infinite dimension and the terms of the complex not.   Or we could have $0 \to \mathbb Z/2 \to^{\cdot 1}  \mathbb Z/2 \to 0$ with the homologies having having $0$ dimension, but the terms of the complex not.

(As Fernando asked, am I interpreting your question correctly?)